# Inherit template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, template-inheritance

I am able to render the `home.html`
 and it prints `Mary had a little lamb` which is `sitetitle`

Here is the code for `home.html`

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{sitetitle}}</h1>
<h1>{% block fun %} {% endblock %}</h1>
</body>
```

But it is not rendering the `fun` block in `title.html`, although it is in the same directory.

Here is the code for `title.html`

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block fun %}
{{ link }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the code for `views.py`
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from models import siteprop
    from django.template import loader

```
def testf(request) :
 obj=siteprop.objects.first()
 context=obj.__dict__
 if '_state' in context: 
 del context['_state']
 print context
 return render(request,"home.html",context)
```

Here is the code for `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from thingslab import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^test/',views.testf,),
]
```

Comment: Please show your views.py and urls.py code

Comment: why are you using h1 tag in fun block ?

Comment: gamer for heading size

Answer (score 3):

The `fun` block in `title.html` is not rendering because in your view you're rendering `home.html`.

Django does not automatically know that the code of `title.html` should be included in `home.html` just because it also contains a `fun` block.

You have to render `title.html` instead of `home.html`:

```
 return render(request, "title.html", context)
```